# Django HTML Post wrong button value

Tags: html, django

POST is sending me the wrong button value, it seems that it send the id of the last student. Instead of assigning each button with unique student_id.

```
        {% for student in student_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ student.firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ student.lastname }}</td>
                {% if student.id in class_list %}
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Details</a></td>
                {% else %}
                    <td><form name="book" method="post" action="{% url 'site:booking' %}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="{{ student.id }}" />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Book Student">
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where's the end form tag?

Comment: @DanielRoseman wow i had no idea that missing tag caused alot of problems. Thanks mate :)